# How to translate date in rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to translate a date in full into my language but I am getting I18n error.

The code below give me an answer in English (standard)

```
expect(page).to have_content 1.day.from_now.strftime("%d de %B de %Y %H:%M")
```

If I use localize to translate the following code I got the error:
I18n::ArgumentError:
Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "13 de February de 2023 20:00" given.

```
expect(page).to have_content I18n.l(1.day.from_now.strftime("%d de %B de %Y %H:%M"))
```

The view is already translated, no issues in view:

```
<h2>Refeição em <%= I18n.l ml.meal_date, :format => "%d de %B de %Y %H:%M" %></h2>
```

**So how's the correct way to get the date correctly translated into RSPEC?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't do dynamic tests in RSpec. It is preferable to have an expected output ex. comparing String to String

You can stub the exact date you want to test for example using the `Timecop` gem, render the page, then simply use assert_select `<css-selector>, label:<Expected text>`

```
it "have english time format" do 
  new_time = Time.local(2023, 2, 13, 20, 0, 0)
  Timecop.freeze(new_time)

  # code to render your page
  assert_select 'h2', label: '13 de February de 2023 20:00', count: 1
end
```